# Setting a SQL Server instance back to multi user mode

Tags: sql-server, configuration

I had to restore a database, but some of the users were still connected, and had left for the day. Previously, I had set the database to single user, now I do not see that option.

So, I made a change at instance level, setting *Properties/Connections/Maximum number of concurrent users* to 1, disconnecting all other users from the server.

I restarted the SQL Server service, but now I am unable to access the database at all. The database is up and running, but I can't open a query window or right click on Properties to revert the change.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 12):

First thing, never set *Max Number of Concurrent Connections* on the server properties page to 1. This option can even prevent administrators logging in, but in any case the Dedicated Administrator Connection can still be used.

1. Restart services using SQL Server Configuration Manager, try to login and if not successful, use the [Dedicated Administrator Connection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178068(v=sql.105).aspx).
2. Right click on the Instance name, and change the value for *Max Number of Concurrent Connections* to 0 (which means maximum) and restart services.

Sometimes, after setting *Max Number of Concurrent Connections* to 1, on login you may face the following error message:

> Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
>   Login failed for user ‘UserName’

To fix this: In the login window, click on the *Options* button and in the *default database* item, select a database like *tempdb* and then press login.

#### If the database is in Single_User mode

Using T-SQL:

```
USE [master];
GO
ALTER DATABASE [YourDatabaseNameHere] SET MULTI_USER WITH NO_WAIT;
GO
```

Using SSMS:

- Right click on required database --> *Properties*
- On the left of Database properties window, click on *Options*
- On the righthand side, scroll down and at bottom you will find a *status* section
- Change the *Restrict Access* value to *multi_user*

If the database is in *Single_User* mode, and you want to change it to Multi_User, but can't access it as someone else already have the connection, then:

1. If you have `ALTER ANY CONNECTION` rights (part of *sysadmin* and *processadmin* fixed server roles), run `SP_WHO` or `SP_WHO2`, find the process using the target database and execute:

   ```
   KILL processid (Ex: KILL 87)
   ```

   then execute above T-SQL to bring your database back to *multi_user*.
2. Or, you can detach and then attach your database and execute the T-SQL above to bring it to *multi_user*. This is not recommended on production servers.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Assim's solution, you want to check your SQLAgent and stop and disable all of the jobs.  I've had to go in and do this for DBAs who were killing processes only to have another one spin up right behind it.  Don't forget to reenable the jobs!